# Pydantic - Use schema field as field type in another schema

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

Is this concept somehow possible in Pydantic:

```
## one file
class StatusOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str


## another file
class UserOut(BaseModel):
    name: str
    status_name: StatusOut.name  ## IS THIS ACHIEVABLE???
```

I get an error "AttributeError: type object 'StatusOut' has no attribute 'name'"

Comment: You wan't it to be `str`, or you meant to do some sort of foreign key

Comment: If I only use ```StatusOut```, then the ```status_name``` would be a ```dict {id, name}```. But I would like to send to the user just the status_name, as a string that contains the ```name``` attribute, and it should be pulled from the ```dict {id, name}```.

Comment: How do you intend the relation to be validated that it is an actual valid `StatusOut.name` and not any plain string (which is what your `UserOut` schema describes in the answer below)? The only thing the version below does that a single `str` wouldn't do is to make any type hints wrong and confuse those who read the code (since the parameter isn't used as the type it is defined as). Maybe you want to use an `Enum` instead? If you want the parameter to be a string, define it as `str` and use the validator to make sure it is a valid `StatusOut.name`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first and only thing I got in mind is to override validation with `@validator(...)` decorator.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class StatusOut(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str


class UserOut(BaseModel):
    name: str
    status_name: StatusOut

    @validator("status_name")
    def redefine_status_name(cls, v):
        return v.name


status = StatusOut(id=1, name="status")

user = UserOut(name="test", status_name=status)

print(user.json())  # {"name": "test", "status_name": "status"}
```

I guess there is no need to explain what I did, I just returned `StatusOut().name` instead of `StatusOut` itself

Although I do not suggest doing that, as it makes `status_name`'s real type not the one that is declared and might confuse you in future

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot! I will wait to mark it as correct after some time passes, to see if there are maybe some builtin solutions. But this works. To avoid the confusion you mentioned I used ```status_name: Union[str, StatusOut]```. That shows in the docs a string return type instead of a dict/object.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. Good thinking.  
It works but is not very really readable. I think the purpose for a use case like the OPs is:   
1: to communicate "Hey, this attribute references the other models attribute".   
2: to be DRY e.g. when long Literals list come into play...  

I guess this solution will just confuse most people and therefore works against "1" What a bummer.